# Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') while parsing json

Tags: json, web-services, spring-restcontroller, objectmapper

> when i hit the url i got the respose in json

```
[{"action":"rs","version":"5","productCatalogName":"tet","productId":"1252","price":"1.5","operator_Code":"15252"}]
```

i am using the object mapper to read the response from url and store it into the object

```
eventProductDetail = objectMapper.readValue(url,
                    new TypeReference<EventProductDetail>() {
                    });
```

> i am getting Exception:

```
Exception ing etProductDetails com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'http': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Comment: What is the type of `url` variable?

Comment: Thankx for your comment.... i was passing String ... now i have changes it to URL type now its woking fine